# Symmetric margins in memoir

Tags: memoir

I want to typeset a book in A5 format with `memoir` with the standard text width provided by `\lxvchars` in that package (this makes sure there are approximately 65 characters on each line). I want the edge margins to be (say) 1.5 times larger than the spine margins. I then want the upper and lower margins to be the same size as the edge margins. The sum of the edge and spine margins isequal to

```
\stockwidth - \lxvchars,
```

and the edge margin is `1.5/(1+1.5) = 3/5` times this. So the entire text block should have height

```
\stockheight - 2*3/5*(\stockwidth - \lxvchars) = \stocheight - 1.2\stockwidth + 1.2\lxvchars.
```

Therefore, I run the following code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\def\myratio{1.2}
\settypeblocksize{\dimexpr\stockheight-\myratio\stockwidth+\myratio\lxvchars}{\lxvchars}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}

\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]


\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}    
    \noindent\lipsum[1-222]
\end{document}
```

Guess what, it doesn't work! The upper right corner looks like below. Notice that the distance from the text to the top is slightly greater than the distance from the text to the right edge. How do I fix this?

[image]

**EDIT:** Per request, here is the same picture with the package `showframe` loaded:

[image]

The entire page can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: Are you using `microtype`?

Comment: Yep, as noted in the MWE. :-)

Comment: Top/bottom/edge margins seem to match now, right?

Comment: @Werner, you appear to be right.

Comment: Never mind, I thought you were bothered by the protrusion in your close-up, but I see that's not the problem.

Comment: You get a +1 for trying anyway. :-)

Comment: I can't see any difference: yes, the text is slightly lower, but the “upper right corner of the text” doesn't really make  sense, because it depends on what letter is typeset there, so you'll have some offset anyway: it's the line that counts. There is a problem in what you're trying, anyway: you want the height to be 1.5 times the width, but the height should always fill an integer number of lines.